# What exactly does '[:]' mean in the example of ipyparallel?

Tags: python

Looking at an example of `ipyparallel` [HERE](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) I see the following code example:

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
c = ipp.Client()
c[:].apply_sync(lambda : "Hello, World")
```

What is the meaning of the part `c[:]`? What does it mean? What does it do? Why is it used in that way?

Comment: @Ch3steR: `c` is not a list.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica My bad. I thought it was normal list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing or slicing an `ipyparallel.Client` instance creates an [`ipyparallel.DirectView`](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/ipyparallel.html#ipyparallel.DirectView) over the execution engines selected by the index or slice. `[:]` selects all engines. The resulting `DirectView` can be used to execute code on the selected engines.

This is covered in one of the [later sections](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/direct.html) of the tutorial.

Comment: So it is a conversion into a list?

Comment: @Alex: No. It creates an `ipyparallel.DirectView`.

Comment: Do you have another example of the '[:]usage?' Or can you convert the example into a similar code without the use of '[:']?

Comment: So whenever I have ANY list in python and I use `[:]` this will always create a `ipyrarallel.DirectView` object?

Comment: @Alex: No. `c` is not a list. List slicing does something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210977/discussion-between-alex-and-user2357112-supports-monica).

Comment: I do not find the answer in the tutorial. Can you point out the exact page please where the `[:]` syntax is explained? Or is this an overloaded operator?

Comment: @Alex: It's on the page I linked. As for whether this is an overloaded operator, every operator implementation in Python uses the same operator overload system, even things like `2 + 3` - there is no distinction between overloads and "non-overloaded" or "built-in" operators.

Comment: I do not find the explanation on that page. The ONLY explanation that would make sense is that you have to create a shallow copy of the list of clients for some reason. But why do I have to use a copy of that list? THAT is NOT explained in the documentation!!

Comment: @Alex: This is not a list. I don't get why you keep saying that.

Comment: If `c` is not a list, then what does `[:]` mean? Is it a function? I do not understand!

Comment: @Alex: It means whatever `c` says it means, and `c` says it means creating a `DirectView` instance.

Comment: Why use an expression like `[:]` and lot a well-named function, say `c.directview()` which would make MUCH more sense

Comment: @Alex: I don't know. It wasn't my decision.

Comment: But the `[:]` expression is really just like a method?